# Using Android Extension Pack (AEP) on Google Tango

Tags: opengl-es, google-project-tango

I need some OpenGL extensions (ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a) on my Google Tango. glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) lists all the extensions I need, so I'm sure the hardware supports it. While searching for a solution it seems that these extensions are available with API-21 (not quite sure about that).

My device still runs API-19 and I'm able to find out if/how I can update it.

I'm also not able to find a way to use the extensions in API-19.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve any of problems?
I should mention, that I'm using the NDK for this project.

Thanks 
  Kai

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use anything opengl Es 3.1, it have to be API-21.
There is not way you use them on API-19 which is current Project tango at.